# Re-writing the oracle sql query

Tags: sql, oracle11g

my current query is

```
SELECT
STATUS, 
POSTAL_CODE, 
CITY_STATE,
    (case when SERVICE = 1 THEN org_id) end) AS WATER,
    (case when SERVICE = 2 THEN org_id) end) AS COFFEE,
    (case when SERVICE = 3 THEN org_id) end) AS FILTRATION
FROM MAP
WHERE POSTAL_CODE = 02216
```

The result that:

```
Status      Zip     City_State  Water  Coffee  Filtration

Serviceable 02216   BOSTON,MA.  BEL    null   null
Serviceable 02216   BOSTON,MA.  null   BDG    null
Serviceable 02216   BOSTON,MA.  null   null   BEL
```

I would like to collapse this result into one row. Is there some elegant select that I could use or should I just use functions like XMLAGG, XMLELEMENT in order to collapse the result into one row? Also, is there a better way to write those case statements? Possibly using the where clause?

Tried a_horse_with_no_name 's suggestion as below:

```
SELECT  STATUS, 
        POSTAL_CODE,
        SERVICE_ITEM_ID,
        MAX((case when SERVICE = 1 THEN org_id)) AS WATER,
        MAX((case when SERVICE = 2 THEN org_id)) AS COFFEE,
        MAX((case when SERVICE = 3 THEN org_id)) AS FILTRATION
FROM MAP
WHERE POSTAL_CODE = '02216'
GROUP BY STATUS, POSTAL_CODE, SERVICE_ITEM_ID;

STATUS  POSTAL_CODE SERVICE_ITEM_ID WATER   COFFEE  FILTRATION
Serviceable 02216   1300            BEL     null        null
Serviceable 02216   1302            null    BDG         null
Serviceable 02216   1304            null    null        BEL
```

Still the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `group by` and an aggregate function:

```
SELECT STATUS, 
       POSTAL_CODE, 
       CITY_STATE,
       max(case when SERVICE = 1 THEN org_id end) AS WATER,
       max(case when SERVICE = 2 THEN org_id end) AS COFFEE,
       max(case when SERVICE = 3 THEN org_id end) AS FILTRATION
FROM MAP
WHERE POSTAL_CODE = '02216'
GROUP BY status, postal_code, city_state
```

As aggregates ignore `NULL` values, this gets reduced into a single row.

---

I assume `postal_code` is a `varchar` column, therefor you should also compare it to a string/varchar value. `02216` is a number (2216), whereas `'02216'` is a string.

Comment: I need as one row, I don't know if you have typo there "into a single column."?

Comment: And how come you're doing max on varchar?

Comment: @NomanArain: as I said: you need to use _some_ aggregate function that returns a single value. `max()` or `min()` doesn't make a difference in this case.

Comment: Hey, how does this make sense? That org_id is a varchar... and why would I want to return one value? org_id is a 3 letter organization code. I wouldn't want to pull just one from it.

Comment: @NomanArain: "*and why would I want to return one value*" - because your question is: "*I would like to collapse this result into one row*" and for that you have to pick one value from the rows that are returned. Did you actually try my statement rather than just wondering what the `max()` does?

Comment: You sir, are not very good at explaining :( Yes, your code *seems* to be working.

Comment: @NomanArain: so what exactly is your question then? I don't get it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using PIVOT (I think it's only good for Oracle 11g and after though).  Also, i'm new to them, but I'm 99% sure it's how you will get everything on one row like you want.

`SELECT *
FROM 
(
SELECT STATUS, 
       POSTAL_CODE, 
       CITY_STATE,
       (max(case when SERVICE = 1 THEN org_id end) AS WATER ||
       max(case when SERVICE = 2 THEN org_id end) AS COFFEE ||
       max(case when SERVICE = 3 THEN org_id end) AS FILTRATION) AS S1
FROM MAP
WHERE POSTAL_CODE = '02216'
GROUP BY status, postal_code, city_state
)
PIVOT 
(
S1
FOR S1 IN ('WATER', 'COFFEE', 'FILTRATION')
)`

Comment: Hey I've been trying the pivot function, but I am not understanding it.

Comment: I am getting "only simple column names allowed here" error at FOR ORG_ID IN ('1', '2', '3')

Comment: Hopefully someone can help here on it. I'm new to pivots myself.  try reading up on: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/sql/11g-pivot-097235.html